# Wicket JQuery Selectable Sortable combined

Tags: jquery, wicket

The Wicket - jQuery UI Api shows an example of a sortable List view: http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/sortable/DefaultSortablePage?6

I would not only like to sort a list, but to delete single elements within the list by clicking on a button, see for example:

```
<ul wicket:id="sortable" class="sortable">
        <li wicket:id="items">
            <span wicket:id="item" class="item">[label]</span>
            <img wicket:id="deleteButton"/>
        </li>
</ul>
```

How is it possible to receive those click events so that I know which list elements has been selected by the user? Is there a way to combine it with the Selectable approach, see http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/selectable/DefaultSelectablePage?7 ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do that like this:

```
<li wicket:id="items">
   <span wicket:id="item" class="item">[label]</span>
   <a wicket:id="deleteButton">DEL</a> <!-- add new link for delete -->
</li>
```

And in java

```
@Override
protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> item)  {
    item.add(new EmptyPanel("icon").add(AttributeModifier.append("class", "ui-icon " + JQueryIcon.ARROW_2_N_S)));
    item.add(new Label("item", item.getModelObject()));
    item.add(AttributeModifier.append("class", "ui-state-default"));
    item.add(new AjaxLink("deleteButton") {
          public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
             // remove item from list by item.getModelObject() 
             // reload sortable component like target.add(sortable)
          }
    });
}
```